# Session upload progress with zend framework 2

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am trying to implement session upload with zf2, but it fails with 
"No upload in progress".

I am using ZfcUser and HtSession.

Have tried to work with provided example module https://github.com/cgmartin/ZF2FileUploadExamples, but i does not work with my project. (Same "no upload in progress")

So far i had tried to make it work with skeleton application, and it works, but when i add ZfcUser module, it gives same message.
As i think, it is because of session maded by zfcUser, but dont know how to avoid such thing.
And in skeleton application + file upload example, if i use ip address it works, if using domain - not("no upload in progress")

Thanks for helping!

**UPD**

If using uploadprogress php extension, both of them(uploadprogress and session progress) returns nothing.

If clear all session and cookies, then i able to upload file.

If i manually add somewhere session , then i dont able see progress, sometimes i get *Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject' in /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-session/src/SessionManager.php on line 109* and session_start() *failed to decode session object. Session had been destroyed* , sometimes just progress return "no upload in progress".

Answer (score 0):

The thing with ZF2's Session Manager configured by default is it saves the session data as object. And if the class of that object is not available to PHP, it won't be able to deserialize it thus the error: missing 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject'.

IMVHO you should [configure the Session Manager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.config.html) to use a different session name instead of default PHPSESSID so it won't interfere with other scripts like your upload-progress-script.

Comment: thats all beause of defalult PHPSESSID? and i make it work with custom jquery file upload script

Comment: I can't tell you for 100% why upload progress is not working, because there are lots of factors to consider: your script may not work properly, your php settings may be invalid apart from dozens of other reasons. What I can tell for sure that ZF2's session will interfere with the default PHPSESSID session and will corrupt it for non ZF2 scripts. First of all you should make sure if the upload progress is working outside of ZF2 in some standalone script or such.

Comment: All scripts outside are working, and as I said before, i dont see changes in session variable.

Comment: Did you try to change the ZF2's session name as I suggested?

Comment: yes, nothing happend. I figuret it out by using other script, but i would like to learn this too.